# why doesn't my JS code recognize mysql database?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to link Node.js with MySQL in vscode.

but it doesn't work.

Here's my code. (mysql.js)

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '1111',
  database : 'mydb1'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('select * from employee', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) {
      console.log(error);
  }
  console.log(results);
});

connection.end();
```

when i run the code "path\node mysql.js"

it gives the ERROR1049 ("Unknown database 'mydb1'") to me.

but when i run the code "show databases;" in terminal.

I can confirm that mydb1 database already exists.
(and mydb1 has also some tables)

why doesn't my JS code recognize mysql database?

any advice will be really appreciated.
please give me some help.

sorry for my english.

Comment: My 'mysql' is using TCP port 3306.

so I add port : 3306 in my code.

but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you connect without choosing the database and then do as the first query `SHOW databases` ?

Comment: the result is like that.

""""""mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mydb1              |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sakila             |
| sys                |
| test               |
| web                |
| world              |
+--------------------+
9 rows in set (0.01 sec)""""""

As i already told you in my question, I can confirm that mydb1 database already exists. 

thank you.

Comment: But I meant making the connection from node without choosing the database at this stage and then doing this (show-dbs-query) query from node and if the database exists choosing it with another query like `USE mydb1`

Comment: Did you mean like this?

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '1111',
  port : 3306
});
 
connection.connect();
 
connection.query('use mydb1', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) {
      console.log(error);
  }
  console.log(results);
});
 
connection.end();
```

it still doesn't work...  it still give me ERROR1049...

Comment: I'm really sorry for my messy comment.. I don't know how to apply code block(```) in comment.

Comment: Wait, it's just like you expected. When i run "show databases" without choosing the database in vscode, there are just " 'information_schema', 'mysql', 'performance_schema', 'sys' ", only these things. But...... why...?

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot do much formatting in the comments. Regarding you problem I don't know :)  I assume that root user should have all the rights to see everything, so maybe somehow it's not the same server that you connect when doing it using terminal vs node? Or maybe the root user has different access rights and in the terminal you connect by default using address `127.0.0.1` and not `localhost`. It could be also something else.

Comment: I did not perfectly interpret your English.

But, you're saying I might have used another server, right?

I'll just reinstall mysql and try again.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I finally solved my problem.

I had two mysqls.

One is installed separately by mysql and the other is installed together by installing "bitnami wamp."

I don't know why, but my JS code approached mysql on the bitnami wamp.

And my "mydb1" is made from another mysql.

This is why the Unknown error occurred.

I don't know if the alarm for this comment goes to you, but I really wanted to thank you.

Because you helped me a lot.

Thank you!

@Picard